# Issue increasing the width of the dialog box in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: trying to replicate the image contents seen here]

I cannot seem to enter a trailing row of icons at the end of each card list view. 
Is there a way of solving this using the same card code or should another method be used?

```
                  showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
```

I decreased the amount of padding to increase the possible available space within the alert dialog box area.

```
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                content: Stack(
                                  overflow: Overflow.visible,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Positioned(
                                      right: -40.0,
                                      top: -40.0,
//                                      width: 600.0,
                                      child: InkResponse(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.close,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                          maxRadius: 20.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Form(
                                      key: _formKey,
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            'Choose a Submission Type',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                                fontSize: 18.0),
                                          ),
                                          Divider(
                                            height: 10.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'This campaign is available to creators with 3000 or more followers.',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                              fontSize: 14.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Card(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                ListTile(
                                                  leading:
                                                      const Icon(Icons.image),
                                                  title: Text(
                                                    'Post',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  subtitle: Text(
                                                    'Single media file',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
```

This is where the issue lies with my code at present. I cannot edit the code to include the two additional icons. What is the best solution for including these trailing icons within this area.

```
//                                                  trailing: Row(
//                                                    children: <Widget>[
//                                                      Icon(
//                                                        FontAwesomeIcons
//                                                            .instagram,
//                                                        size: 10.0,
//                                                      ),
////                                                      Icon(
////                                                        FontAwesomeIcons
////                                                            .facebook,
////                                                        size: 10.0,
////                                                      ),
//                                                    ],
//                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` to the `Row` Like this

```
trailing: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,
        size: 10.0,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 5, 
      ),
      Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.facebook,
        size: 10.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Let me know if this is what you want. I added that `SizedBox` too if that wasn't the look you wan't just take it out